# node.js async.maplimit() pass extra param to processing function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

```
async.eachLimit(rowset.rows, 200, storeRow, postProcessingFunction);

function storeRow(row, cb) {...}
```

How to pass an additional param to `storeRow()` ?

So something like this :

```
async.eachLimit(rowset.rows, 200, storeRow, rowset.param, postProcessingFunction);

function storeRow(row, param, cb) {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't need to do it that way. Instead, you could do something like this:

```
function foo(param) {
  async.eachLimit(rowset, 200, storeRow, postProcessingFunction);
  function storeRow(row, cb) { /* this code uses param */ }
}
```

Comment: thanks cybersam but actually the param is a field on the rowset object (i've edited my post to reflect this)

Comment: @BaltoStar The same idea applies.  You can use the `rowset` variable through closure just as well as the `param` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Use Function.bind to create a "curried" function.

```
function storeRow(propertyFromRowset, row, cb){ /* ... */ };

async.eachLimit(
  rowset.rows,
  200,
  storeRow.bind(null,rowset.property),
  postProcessingFunction
);
```

See [Wikipedia:Currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) for the theory and [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) for details of how to curry a function in Javascript.